# Fastest way to send an email to gmail at exactly 12:00 PM on Saturday

Tags: python, email, scripting, gmail, autohotkey

So for one of my classes we have to send an email to our professor with our preferences for these projects we want to work on in a certain order, and it's a first come first serve thing.  I've been pondering little hackish scripts I could write to try and make it as fast and accurate as possible to get the first email in at 12:00 PM when the Google Time Servers tick to 12:00.

I've thought of little python scripts that use SMTP to connect to GMail or also writing an autohotkey script to simply press the "Send" button on the web interface at the right time as well.  Anyone got a more interesting/reliable method of sending this email so that it ends up in my professor's inbox at exactly 12:00?

Thanks for any brainstorming ideas.

Comment: Given the multiple delays involved before the message reaches the professor and minor inconsistencies in different computers' clocks, it seems like it should suffice to just hit the button when your clock hits 12.

Comment: I agree with "user2357112". Pressing the button manually should be good enough unless you compete against other students all motivated enough to do the same thing. One thing that doesn't work is changing your computer's clock. Google seems to take the time from the time it received the mail. You could check out services like (http://techie-buzz.com/featured/schedule-emails-in-gmail.html) against your own gmail account if they work. I'd expect manually sending to be faster.

Comment: Alas you did not specify if the professor had a gmail or other email address. If you have an email account on the same email system as the professor you should use that to send the mail. Again you should send mails on that system to yourself and examine the time stamps on that to synch against your own clock so you know when midnight strikes on that system.

Comment: You could try and set up a cron job or something that triggers automatically, but that leaves room for error. You should just set the alarm on your phone and sit at your computer with a trigger finger. With Gmail you have the send undo to consider also if you have that turned on. That could cause a 10 sec delay when you hit send.

Comment: Good info everyone.  I will be using a gmail and so will my professor.  We are all CS students so I am pretty sure I won't be the only one trying to create a script for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to use Delay Delivery. Take a look at: [Gmail Delay Send](https://code.google.com/p/gmail-delay-send/)

You compose your message, and you can use Gmail Delay Send to set a time (12:00) for it to send it. Easy.